# Why is it not applying scrollIntoView to the selected element in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I am currently trying to get it to scroll to a section of the view
as follows:

```
mounted: function() {
    const el = this.$el.getElementsByClassName('outstandingStandarItems')[0];
    if(el){
        el.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});
        console.log(el);
    }
  }
```

On the console it prints it like this:
[image]

But this does not apply: `el.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});`

The section I should go to is this:

```
<el-card shadow="never" class="box-card outstandingStandarItems" v-if="isOutstanding">
</el-card>
```

I need it to apply `scrollIntoView` when the view is loaded, that's why I have it in the mounted. If I add it in a method and then add a button to go to that method, then it does apply it correctly.

```
<el-button @click="gotoOutStanding()">GOT OUT</el-button>

gotoOutStanding(){
  this.$refs.outstandingItems.$el.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});
},
```

But I need that to happen automatically when the view loads.

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is in:

```js
const el = this.$el.getElementsByClassName('outstandingStandarItems')[0];
```

you should try with $refs:

```
<el-card shadow="never" ref="items" class="box-card outstandingStandarItems" v-if="isOutstanding">
</el-card>
```

and then:

```
const el = this.$ref.item;
```

for deeper understanding go [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html)

Comment: Already having $ ref the element that I do? How do I apply scrollIntoView?